# What is more effective: every time make an ajax request or slice a result in func?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a JSON data of news like this:

```
{
"news": [
    {"title": "some title #1","text": "text","date": "27.12.15 23:45"},
    {"title": "some title #2","text": "text","date": "26.12.15 22:35"},
    ...
   ]
}
```

I need to get a certain number of this list, depended on an argument in a function. As I understand, its called pagination.
I can get the ajax response and slice it immediately. So that every time the function is called - every time it makes an ajax request.
Like this:

```
function showNews(page) {
var newsPerPage = 5,
    firstArticle = newsPerPage*(page-1);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var newsArr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText),
            ;
        newsArr.news = newsArr.news.slice(firstArticle, newsPerPage*(page));
        addNews(newsArr);
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
```

Or I can store all the result in *newsArr* and slice it in that additional function *addNews*, sorted by pages.

```
function addNews(newsArr, newsPerPage) {
var pages = Math.ceil(amount/newsPerPages), // counts number of pages
    pagesData = {}; 
for(var i=0; i<=pages; i++) { 
    var min = i*newsPerPages, //min index of current page in loop
        max = (i+1)*newsPerPages; // max index of current page in loop
    newsArr.news.forEach(createPageData);
}
function createPageData(item, j) {
    if(j+1 <= max && j >= min) {
        if(!pagesData["page"+(i+1)]) { 
            pagesData["page"+(i+1)] = {news: []};
        }
        pagesData["page"+(i+1)].news.push(item);
    }
}
```

So, simple question is which variant is more effective? The first one loads a server and the second loads users' memory. What would you choose in my situation? :)

**Thanks for the answers. I understood what I wanted. But there is so much good answers that I can't choose the best**

Comment: why don't you change your service to return only n number of records rather than slicing the arrays on UI?

Comment: gurvinder372, you're right, but I need exactly one of this two ways.

Comment: In that case, how many it depends on how many records your service is going to return. If it is less than 1000, then one service call is fine since payload would be not huge, and you can go for option-2.

Comment: Yes best practice would be to do the formatting on the server side, only time you would do client-side would be when the data isn't changing and your just manipulating it, like a table being sorted ascending/descending, where you don't need to pull the data from the server you just need to manipulate the display of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a primarily opinion-based question.

For me, pagination approach looks better because it will not produce "lag" before displaying the news. From user's POV the page will load faster.

As for me, I would do pagination + preload of the next page. I.e., always store the contents of the next page, so that you can show it without a delay. When a user moves to the last page - load another one.

Loading all the news is definitely a bad idea. If you have 1000 news records, then every user will have to load all of them...even if he isn't going to read a single one.

In my opinion, `less requests == better` rule doesn't apply here. It is not guaranteed that a user will read all the news. If StackOverflow loaded all the questions it has every time you open the main page, then both StackOverflow and users would have huge problems.

Comment: that means, that none of this variants will be good enough? better - server-side slice?

Comment: @БогданГусейнов Oh, of course. I though that you choose between server-side slice and pagination vs. getting all the items and client-side slicing. You should use server-side slice. There is no practical sense in getting all the items, and then slicing it at client-side.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev There is: client side caching. Also 1000 records is not heavy at all. Images weight more. Anyway he should try all possibilites and choose the one fits him best.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb:

```
less requests == better
```

but that's not always possible. You may run out of memory/network if the data you store is huge, i.e. you may need pagination on the server side. Actually server side pagination should be the default approach and then you think about improvements (e.g. local caching) if you really need them.

So what you should do is try all scenarios and see how well they behave in your concrete situation.

Answer (score 1):

If the max number of records that your service returns is around 1000, then I don't think it is going to create a huge payload or memory issues (by looking at the nature of your data), so I think **option-2 is better** because

- number of service calls will be less
- since user will not see any lag while paginating, his experience of using the site will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer fetch all data but showing on some certain condition like click on next button data is already there just do hide and show on condition using jquery.

```
Every time call ajax is bad idea.
```

but you also need to call ajax for new data if data is changed after some periodic time